# Nginx fails to record logs unless restarted

Tags: nginx

nginx server fails to record logs in error.log, for any requests it processes. It is only after I restart the nginx server that it starts logging again. Is there any solution?

Comment: please state additional informations, f.e. Server OS, Version, what sort of logrotating you use, if this happens after reboot, after a certain time, if the file is newly created on the "first" run, but only accessed after the restart.

Comment: Linux, Red Hat 6.4, I'm using the default logrotation policy using logrotate.d. The log-files are archived daily. I don't know when the logs stop recording, but this gets fixed when I restart.

Comment: Are the other log files (access.log etc) affected in the same way? How big is the error log when logging stops?

Comment: When someone reports a problem I go check the error log but I see only 1 line `*9 client xxxx closed keepalive connection`. Investigated further and I think there's some prob with postscript in log rotate: ``/bin/kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null || true``